# How to authenticate user from database using Spring rest api and oauth security

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-jdbc, spring-restcontroller

I want to implement Rest api security using oauth2 and I have implemented this security using static user data by following [this](http://sivatechlab.com/secure-rest-api-using-spring-security-oauth2-part-3/). Now I would like to change this case to authenticate data from database using jdbc but till now I'm not able to find any tutorial on jdbc authentication. Please do suggest me some examples of my requirements, My requirement is Spring mvc Rest api+OAuth2+jdbc database+java-config example.

currently I have tested with static users like below.

```
public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
 Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("crmadmin").password("crmpass").roles("ADMIN","USER").and()
    .withUser("crmuser").password("pass123").roles("USER");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure it as below:
Put the code below in the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Autowired
private DataSource securityDataSource; // from Bean where you have connection, jdbc driver set up for database containing login information
```

@Override

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
}
```